# Server cannot run apt-get anymore

Tags: apt, environment-variables, paths

I was trying to setup an older version of gcc (4.1) on ubuntu 14.

I was having some difficulties to set alternatives. I so thread where someone said to use this command:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

after I ran this, something got messed up because I cannot run update commands

```
sudo apt-get update
```

gives me

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

Probably other issue I didn't notice yet but something got broken.

I search for answers, only suggestion I have seen is to re install Ubuntu, but I would to know if there is any fix.

So far I tried to revert this change by running `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games` but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both paths should have /usr/bin which is where apt-get normally lives in Ubuntu 14.04.
You can check where it is in your filesystem: `locate apt-get`, or you can go there and make sure it is actually where you expect it to be: `ls -l /usr/bin/apt*`

If that checks out, double check what your path is actually set to: `echo $PATH` and set it again if somehow `/usr/bin` was lost from that string.